# Google Chrome fails to launch in a VM

Tags: virtual-machine, chrome

Google Chrome fails to launch in a VM and shows these errors:

```
~$ google-chrome-stable
[1210/095138.308075:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[1210/095138.308293:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Comment: do those "files" exist? what sort of PC are you running this on

Comment: these files dont exist and it s not a pc but a VM where i dont have an interface but only the terminal

Comment: this is a red herring. these messages have (probably) nothing to do with your crash. They're pretty common, as chrome tries to figure out how to influence your CPU frequency scaling; if it can't do that, some things might suffer in performance, but it works without (also, honestly, your browser trying to control your CPU scaling: uff. That sounds like a lot of nope.)

Comment: `core dumped` at least you have a core dump to analyse

Comment: What's your VM? What's its configuration? What's the **guest OS and its version**? Do you have **enough RAM**? Do you have enough **free disk space**? Is your `/home` partition **user-writable**?